# Setting the value of a multidimensional object or array property in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, indexing, properties

Yes I know how to loop through arrays (types) in **Javascript**. The fact is, I'd like to know how to set a `multiDimensionalArray` array's value by a set of given `indexes` to keep it as generic as possible. For example I've an array with a length of 3 (which could as well be a length of 4, 100, ...):

`var indexes = [0, "title", "value"];`

I know the multidimensional array (mArray) can be set by putting the indexes like so:

`multiDimensionalArray[0]["title"]["value"] = "Jeroen";` or `multiDimensionalArray[indexes[0]][indexes[1]][indexes[2]] = "Jeroen";`

The fact  that the given indexes array can vary and does not always contain the same index names so I'm search for a solution like this:

`multiDimensionalArray[indexes] = "Jeroen";`

I don't know how to code the assignation if this. I've searched on Google/Stack Overflow. Maybe I'm using the wrong keywords. Can anyone help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following example is how I've made it working thanks to Jonas's example:

```js
var json = [{
  "hello": {
    "world": 1,
    "world2": 2
  },
  "bye": {
    "world": 1,
    "world2": 2
  }
}];

var indexes = [0, "hello", "world2"];
var value = "value";

indexes.slice(0,-1).reduce((obj, index) => obj[index], json)[indexes.pop()] = value;
console.log(json);
```

Answer (score 0):

So imagine you have a structure like this:

```
var array=[[["before"]]];
```

Then you want

```
var indexes=[0,0,0];
var value="value";
```

to actually do:

```
array[0][0][0]="value";
```

which can be easily achieved with reduce:

```
indexes.slice(0,-1).reduce((obj,index)=>obj[index],array)[indexes.pop()]=value;
```

Explanation:

```
indexes.slice(0,-1) //take all except the last keys and
.reduce((obj,index)=>obj[index] //reduce them to the resulting inner object e.g. [0,0] => ["before"]
,array) //start the reduction with our main array
[indexes.pop()]=value;// set the reduced array key to the value
```

```js
    var array=[[[0]]];


    var indexes=[0,0,0];
    var value="value";
    indexes.slice(0,-1).reduce((obj,index)=>obj[index],array)[indexes.pop()]=value;
    
    console.log(array);
```

Comment: How could this work when using textual indexes like mentioned in the question? I cannot seem to get it working when replacing the zeroes in you example by textual indexes. I'm using textual indexes since the multiDimensionalArray can also contain object data.

Comment: It worked by replacing `indexes.slice(-1)` with `indexes.slice(0, -1)`

Comment: @jeroen oh right, thanks for the info. Im sorry for that obvious mistake... :/